# Load data in a function with .map

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, reducers, dispatch

I have the following function who is not working :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getPosts } from '../../actions/post.actions';


const BudgetChart = () => {

const [loadPost, setLoadPost] = useState(true)
const dispatch  = useDispatch()

const posts = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(loadPost) {
            dispatch(getPosts())
            setLoadPost(false)
        }
    }, [loadPost])

const amounts = posts.map(post => post.amount);

const income = amounts
    .filter(post => post.nature === 'ca')
    .reduce((acc, post) => acc + post.amount, 0)

    console.log(amounts)
    console.log(income)


    return (
        <div>
            CA Total = {income}
        </div>
    )
}

export default BudgetChart
```

The const amounts = posts.map(post => post.amount) is not working.
The error is "posts.map is not a fucntion".

Here what I have in my reducer :

```
import { GET_POSTS } from "../actions/post.actions";

const initialState = {}

export default function postReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_POSTS:
            return action.payload
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

So far it is only working like that :

```
return (
      <div>
          <ul>
          {!isEmpty(posts[0]) && 
          <li>
             CA Total : {posts.filter(post => post.nature === 'ca')
                              .reduce((acc, post) => acc + post.amount, 0)
                              }
          </li>
            }
          </ul>
```

What am I missing ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: and if you put `const posts = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer)` after the `useEffect`?

Comment: I tried, it does not work but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `.map` because `posts` is not an array.  The initial state of your reducer is an object.

```
const initialState = {}
```

If it's meant to be an array, make the initial state an empty array `[]` and also make sure that the `action.payload` of `GET_POSTS` is an array.